# .,Is it possible to have multiple simultaneous DVD drives on XenServer?

Tags: xenserver, optical-media

I'd like to be able to have more than 1 CD/DVD available at a time for a XenServer VM.

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125520

That article is the closest to what I'm asking for, but it didn't work. I am running XenServer 6.5 SP1. I asked on Citrix forums a while ago, but didn't get any responses.

Edit: Even loading CDs from a drive is buggy. Either the Windows guest won't recognize anything loaded, or it freezes the OS (trying to access the CD drive) for a while.

Comment: The instructions you posted should work fine. What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? Need more details on your actual problem.

Comment: By "doesn't work", running the final command says "Required parameter not found: cd-name". This command feels like it's for loading/unloading CD images, not a drive itself.